# Apollo GQL - Clear cache for one type only

Tags: apollo-client, gql

I would like to be able to clear the cache of only one specified type

e.g. if I have Authors and Books I would like to only clear cache for `Authors`

I'm using `@apollo/client": "^3.2.5"` (latest)

Just additional note, shouldn't matter much but I'm using it with Angular.

```
apollo.client.clearStore(); // this clears all store
```

Tried to use the `apollo.client.cache.writeQuery`, however no luck yet

Remove by the `__typename` would be ideal or something related

Answer (score 2):

Using the v3 it seems by using the evict api is doing what I needed

```
this.apollo.client.cache.evict({
    fieldName: "authors",
});
```